# Trigger a function when user scrolls through a section list

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm new to react-native.

I'm trying to build a component with a section list and a segment tab controller that holds the list sections.

I need to know what section the user is currently scrolling,  I want to be able to set the selected segment as the user slide through the sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onViewableItemsChanged` is probably what you want to use.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist#onviewableitemschanged